# Render narrow font on a transparent PNG with PHP

Tags: php, fonts, gd

I'm trying to properly render some text in a transparent image (I will then add this generated image in another image). The problem is PHP and alpha transparency act weird when it comes to font that are narrow.

Here is the code used :
(using https://github.com/stil/gd-text library to render the text)

```
<?php

require_once (dirname(__FILE__).'/vendor/autoload.php');

class TextImage
{
    protected $text;
    protected $width;
    protected $height;
    protected $font;
    protected $colorR;
    protected $colorG;
    protected $colorB;
    protected $size;

    /**
     * 
     * @param int $width Image width
     * @param int $height Image height
     * @param string $font Font path
     */
    public function __construct($text=null, $width=null, $height=null, $font=null, $colorR=null, $colorG=null, $colorB=null, $size=null)
    {
        $this->width = $width;
        $this->height = $height;
        $this->font = $font;
        $this->colorR = $colorR;
        $this->colorG = $colorG;
        $this->colorB = $colorB;
        $this->size = $size;
        $this->text = $text;
    }

    public function render()
    {
        // create image for the given width/height
        $image = imagecreatetruecolor($this->width, $this->height);

        // apply transparence
        imagealphablending($image, false);
        imagesavealpha($image, true);
        $transparent = imagecolorallocatealpha($image, 0,0,0, 127);
        imagefill($image, 0, 0, $transparent);

        // now use GDText to add the text
        $box = new \GDText\Box($image);
        $box->setFontFace($this->font);
        $box->setFontColor([$this->colorR, $this->colorG, $this->colorB]);
        //$box->setTextShadow([0, 0, 0, 50], 2, 2);
        $box->setFontSize($this->size);
        //$box->setLeading(0.8);
        $box->setBox(0, 0, $this->width, $this->height);
        $box->setTextAlign('center', 'center');
        $box->draw($this->text);

        // output
        header("Content-type: image/png");
        imagepng($image);
    }
}
```

Here is the test case:

```
$test = new TextImage('Exemple', 200, 30, 'Exmouth.ttf', 0, 0, 0, 20);
$test->render();
```

I'm using that font: http://www.dafont.com/exmouth.font

Here is the rendered image:

[image: Exemple]

See how the text is broken? And it's not always the case. Here is another exemple with some other text:

[image: Some other text]

And If I don't do transparency then it looks fine. Maybe I should switch to another solution to render transparent text?

Note: if I change font & picture size It doesn't change anything to the transparency problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by the line `imagealphablending($image, false);`. Removing this causes the text to render correctly.  This still produces an image with what appears to be intact alpha-channel data, so I expect you can use it for your subsequent merge.

As to why this happens... I have no idea.  I can't reproduce the problem with another font.  My best guess is that somehow the font is not playing nicely with GD, either due to a bug in GD or because of a problem in how the font is designed.